# Repository not implementing interface correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern

The error I am getting is

> Error 1   'OCDSandbox.Models.OrganizationRepository' does not implement
>   interface member
>   'OCDSandbox.Models.IRepository.FindByOrgNbr()'    C:\source
>   temp\OCDSandbox\OCDSandbox\Models\OrganizationRepository.cs   line 9

**OrganizationRespository.CS**

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OCDSandbox.Models
{

    public class OrganizationRepository : IRepository
    {
        private GMS_Sandbox_testDataContext _dataContext;


        public OrganizationRepository()
        {
            _dataContext = new GMS_Sandbox_testDataContext();
        }



        public IList<Organization> ListAll()
        {
            var organizations = from o in _dataContext.Organizations
                select o;
            return organizations.ToList();
        }

        public ICollection<Organization> FindAll()
        {
            return _dataContext.Organizations.ToList();
        }

        public ICollection<Organization> FindByOrgNbr(string OrgNbr)
        {
            var organizations = _dataContext.Organizations.Where(p => p.org_nbr == OrgNbr).ToList();
            return organizations;
        }

    }
}
```

**IRepository.CS**

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OCDSandbox.Models
{
    public interface IRepository
    {
        // organization interface
        IList<Organization> ListAll();
        ICollection<Organization> FindAll(); //returns list read only
        ICollection<Organization> FindByOrgNbr();

    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is my first time using repo and I would like to then test FindByOrgNbr in controller. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FindByOrgNbr does not expect parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a parameter in the interface in the definition of FindByOrgNbr

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OCDSandbox.Models
{
    public interface IRepository
    {
        // organization interface
        IList ListAll();
        ICollection FindAll(); //returns list read only
        ICollection FindByOrgNbr(string OrgNbr);

    }
}
```

Comment: wow should have looked closer. Thanks! Now it says "No overload for method 'FindByOrgNbr' takes 0 arguments

Comment: you need to call FindByOrgNbr method with a parameter

Comment: I am calling it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks because the interface has this method: `ICollection<Organization> FindByOrgNbr();` and your class has `public ICollection<Organization> FindByOrgNbr(string OrgNbr)`

It seems the interface needs the OrgNbr parameter too.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `OrgNbr` parameter in your interface definition for `FindByOrgNbr()`.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    // organization interface
    IList<Organization> ListAll();
    ICollection<Organization> FindAll(); //returns list read only
    ICollection<Organization> FindByOrgNbr(string OrgNbr);
}
```